# Elements of $\mathbb{Q}(e)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Is $e^n$ for $n$ an integer an element of the field $\mathbb{Q}(e)$?

Comment: Yes it is, the extension is a field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes !

Obviously $e \in \mathbb{Q}(e)$, but $\mathbb{Q}(e)$ is a field, then the product $e*e \in \mathbb{Q}(e)$ and by induction $e^n \in \mathbb{Q}(e)$ for every n.

Comment: How can I write an arbitrary element of $\mathbb{Q}(e)$? I thought it was $a + be$ for $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$ but that doesn't allow for powers of $e$...

Comment: @TatianaBradley:  Assuming $e$ is "$e$", as in $\ln e = 1$, any element of $\Bbb Q(e)$ may be written as $p(e)/q(e)$ for $p(x), q(x) \in \Bbb Q[x]$.  Right?  Cheers!

Comment: ^ +1
No necessarily every element of $\mathbb{Q}(e)$ has the form $a + be$, with $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$.
mmm, $e$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: One can do better if we have an algebraic extension, but even then $a+be$ is usually not achievable, example $e=2^{1/3}$.

Comment: I thought e is the Euler number? This is transcendental.